# Problem in solving the non-linear equation

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations, findinstance, resolve

Is there any other way to solve an equation rather than solve command also without findroot command in Mathematica? Because the `Solve` command is not returning any result and using the `FindRoot` command does provide the desired result. The equation is `x^2+a^2+2 n a x+Exp[\frac{-x}{(n-\frac{\alpha L}{2}]=0`. So how can I get the solution for `x`  and `\alpha` value?

`Solve[x^2+a^2+2 n a x+Exp[\frac{-x}{(n-\frac{\alpha L}{2}]=0,x]`

Comment: Please load Mathematica code that can be copied, pasted and executed in our own notebook sessions. Thanks.

Comment: IF AND ONLY IF this `x^2+a^2+2 n a x+Exp[-x/((n-α L)/2)]==0` is your equation then I don't believe there is any way to solve for x using `Solve` or `Reduce` or any other function in Mathematica that does not use `FindRoot` or some other numerical root finding method. That is often the case for problems that involve both x and Exp[x] along with a few other terms.